# Goのローカルインポートについて

Tags: go

以下のディレクトリ構成で`inqueryHandlers.go`内で `import "project_name/model"`として`inquery.go`ないのStructを`inqueryhandlers.go`ないで使用しました。ところが`undefined`でエラーが出てさらにインポート箇所で`not used`とでてしまいます。
`import "../model"`ではこのエラーが出ないのですが、今度は`../model" in non-local package`というエラーが出てビルドに失敗してしまいます。

この場合どのようにインポートすればいいのでしょうか

ディレクトリ構成

```html
├── handlers
│   ├── inqueryHandlers.go
│   └── proxyHandlers.go
├── loger.go
├── main.go
├── model
│   └── inquery.go
├── router.go
└── routes.go
```

inquery.go

```html
// Inquery is a model.
type Inquery struct {
    Id      int       `json: "id"`
    Content string    `json: "content"`
    Created time.Time `json: "created"`
}

// Inqueries are models.
type Inqueries []Inquery
```

Comment: 相対パス import の問題に関する mattn 氏の[コメント](http://qiita.com/tyochiai/items/d93f7540d9cf4f0a01bd#comment-be5ec7584a752f28cb4f)が参考になるかもしれません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

仕方ないので現状以下のようにモデルをまとめてpackageでまとめるのを諦めました;;

```html
├── inqueryHandlers.go
├── loger.go
├── main.go
├── models.go
├── proxyHandlers.go
├── router.go
└── routes.go
```

Answer (score 0):

ぐぐったらでてきました

http://qiita.com/shiwork/items/a213b1af2da7f7f8ea22

今作業されているディレクトリが`$GOPATH`配下にいたりしますか？

Comment: そうです。GOPATH配下のsrcディレクトリにプロジェクトをおいています。

Comment: であれば、GOPATH配下「ではない」ディレクトリに移動させてみてください

Comment: それだとgo getで取得したライブラリを使えなくなるのではないですか。

Comment: `go get`で取得したライブラリは、プロジェクトがGOPATH配下にいなくても使えます。

Comment: 今試してみました。go getで取得したライブラリは使えましたが、`inqueryHandlers.go`内で`impoert "./../model"`とするとなぜか使っているのに`imported and not used`とmodelパッケージ使用箇所で`not found`が出てしまいました。

Comment: それは文字通り、`inqueryHandlers.go`の中でmodelパッケージ内のstructや関数などを使っていないからでは？

Comment: 使っているのですが使用箇所で`not found ○○`エラーがでてしまいました｡

Comment: `not found xxx`(xxxはメソッド名など)は、差し支えなければどのような関数/structか教えていただけないでしょうか？

Comment: inquery.go内定義したstructです。本文に追記しました。

Comment: ありがとうございます。inqueryHandlers.goの中ではどのようにこれらのstructを使用していますか？（無いとは思いますが`var i Inquery`のようにしてたりしないかなと。。）